# Printing the minimum & maximum counts for elements within Iist of output, from a function as well as the item itself

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, python-2.7

```
mik=[]

def(example):
    for i in range(count):
        for j in range(count):
```

"function etc."

```
                 a = str(mar)
                 b = str(chi)
                 c = float(dist)
                 d = float(dost)
                 mylist=[a,b,c,d]
                 if c>0:
                    if d>c:
                       mik.append(a)
                       print a
```

Now i get the output for example

```
AB01
AB02
AB02
AB04
BH22
```

I'm trying to find the most common word (yes even if there is 2 or 3 etc. that occur that amount of times) in this (list? array? set?) and print the times it occurs (yes even if there is 2 or 3 etc.) and print the number of times that element occurs as well. Do I need to define another function? I tried that and the mik was out of range. I've tried min and max and im realazing that dosent work on strings, at least mine,these in this case. Would sorting do something?

From this im trying to output

```
  Minimum Occurrence Number: 1
  Codes that Occur this much: ABO1 ABO4 BH22
  Maximum Occurrence Number: 2
  Codes that Occur this much: ABO2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `collections` module and `Counter`.

What you are trying to do can be done by:

```
from collections import Counter
common = Counter(yourList).most_common()
min = common[0][1]
print "Minimum Occurrence Number: {0}".format(min)
print "Codes that Occur this much:"
for item in common:
    if item[1] != min:
        break
    print item[0]
max = common[-1][1]
print "Maximum Occurrence Number: {0}".format(max)
print "Codes that Occur this much:"
for item in reversed(common):
    if item[1] != max:
        break
    print item[0]
```

Comment: I just did a quick update, just to check your solution will still work @mattbryant

Comment: This did not work, it returned all the entries in the list and how many times they occur

Comment: thanks so much, unfortantly i already used min before further above in the code, and its still giving me every value in the list.  Min com count: 1 Tow with min : AA11 Max com count: 1 Tow with max: AA11

Comment: Is the list only 1 item long?  I need more information to be able to help.

Comment: when i type print a indented like 5 times over stilll in the for loop it prints aaaa then next line bbbb then next line and so on, no quotes, no commas, if i do print a from the left start side it says it dosent exsist

Comment: thanks! i just posted another question about counts in lists and dealing with means, maybe you know how to write the function properly?